# Matrix calculation with PBLAS algorithm - multi threads with MPI

Tags: c, matrix, mpi, distributed-computing

I'm currently developping a C code with mpi for matrix multiplication. I have functions already implemented as mult or multadd defined in an other file, working well.
But my file `pblas.c` compiles, but crashes when running.

I run my project on a university server, which has `mli` installed.

Where am i wrong in my `pblas` code ?

```
/**********************************************************************

This file is just a pattern for pblas parallel multiplication

There are comments beginning with TO ADD that tell what must be done
where they are placed. Thus, just add the correct lines of code and
everything will work fine !

*********************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "commfct.h"
#include "toolsfct.h"

void usage() {

  fprintf(stderr,"usage : pblas bloc_size\n\t bloc_size : gives the size of blocs owned by each processor.\n");
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int me,nbProc;
  int ligMe,colMe;
  int blockSize;
  int i,j;
  double t;

  if (argc != 2) {
    usage();
  }

  blockSize = atoi(argv[1]);

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &me);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nbProc);

  int P = (int)sqrt(nbProc); // P = the number of rows of proc.
  int Q = P; // Q = the number of columns of proc.
  if ((P*Q) != nbProc) {
    if (me == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr,"!!! CRITICAL ERROR : number of processors must be 4, 9, 16, ...\nAborting\n");
    }
    exit(1);
  }

  createGridComm(me,P,Q);

  ligMe = me / Q;
  colMe = me % Q;

  // allocate memory for matrices
  double *A,*Btmp, *B,*C,*CC;
  A = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));
  B = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));
  Btmp = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));
  C = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));
  CC = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));

  /* fill blocks with pseudo values

     NOTE : these values should not be changed so that
     the check below is valid
   */

  for(i=0;i<blockSize*blockSize;i++) {
    A[i] = 2.0+(double)me;
    B[i] = 1.0+(double)colMe;
    C[i] = (double)me / 10.0;
  }


  /* CAUTION : in the following, A,B C are supposed to be stored
     column after column, with each column of size blockSize.
     Thus A(0,0) and A(1,0) are contiguous in memory, but
     A(0,0) and A(0,1) are separated by blockSize cells.
  */

  t = dclock(CLOCK_S);

MPI_Status status;
//main Loop
for(i=0;i<P;i++) {
  /*************************************
Etape 1 et 2: Transposition  column i (in step i) of B-blocks . stock in Btmp.  
**************************************/

if(colMe==i){

    if(ligMe==colMe) {
    MPI_Bcast(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,ligMe,commCol);   
    multadd(A,B,C,blockSize);
    }   
    else {
        int dest = colMe * Q + ligMe;
        MPI_Send(B,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,dest,TAG_TRANSPOSE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,dest%Q,commCol);
        mult(A,Btmp,CC,blockSize);
        }
}
else {

    int dest = colMe*Q + ligMe;
    if(dest%Q == i) {
    MPI_Recv(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,dest,TAG_TRANSPOSE,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    // Broadcast on the column
    MPI_Bcast(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,colMe,commCol);
    multadd(A,Btmp,C,blockSize);
    }
    else {
    MPI_Bcast(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,i,commCol);
    mult(A,Btmp,CC,blockSize);
    }

}

if(colMe == i)
    MPI_Reduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, C, blockSize*blockSize, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, colMe, commLine);
else
    MPI_Reduce(CC,NULL,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,i,commLine);

}
  t = dclock(CLOCK_S) -t;

  printf("timing for %d : %f sec\n",me,t);

  // checking for result correctness
  int correct = 1;
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(i=0;i<P;i++) {
    sum += 2.0+(ligMe*Q)+(double)i;
  }

  for(i=0;i<blockSize;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<blockSize;j++) {
      if (C[i+j*blockSize] != ((double)me/10.0 + sum*blockSize*(colMe+1.0))) {
    correct = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  if (correct != 1) {
    printf("multiplication result is not correct\n");
  }

  // free memory
  free(A);
  free(B);
  free(C);
  free(CC);

  releaseGridComm();

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know which line it's crashing on?

Comment: A lot more guidance on what you've tried. Exactly what the error is and where its occurring, etc. is needed. It's not a lot of fun to just debug other people's code here if you don't make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble may come from indexes in MPI_Send(), MPI_Recv() or MPI_Bcast(). For instance, in MPI_Send(), the destinator shall call MPI_Recv(). In MPI_Recv(), the origin should have called MPI_Send(). Otherwise, you will get a deadlock. The code keeps on running, but it waits for messages.

From what you gave us, I guess you have two matrix A and B.

A0 | A1

...........

A2 | A3

To compute the first column of C, you need :

A0xB0  |  A1xB2

...................

A2xB0  |  A3xB2

I changed your code so that :

for each column i

i_th column of B is transposed in the i_th line of Btmp

i_th line of Btmp is broadcast to Btmp in each column.

Since the issue was about MPI, i reply with a MPI code that looks very close to yours, works but it does nothing, except communication operations...

```
/**********************************************************************

This file is just a pattern for pblas parallel multiplication

There are comments beginning with TO ADD that tell what must be done
where they are placed. Thus, just add the correct lines of code and
everything will work fine !

 *********************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

//#include "commfct.h"
//#include "toolsfct.h"

#define TAG_TRANSPOSE 42

void usage() {

    fprintf(stderr,"usage : pblas bloc_size\n\t bloc_size : gives the size of blocs owned by each processor.\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int me,nbProc;
    int ligMe,colMe;
    int blockSize;
    int i,j;
    double t;

    if (argc != 2) {
        usage();
    }

    blockSize = atoi(argv[1]);

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &me);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nbProc);

    int P = (int)sqrt(nbProc); // P = the number of rows of proc.
    int Q = P; // Q = the number of columns of proc.
    if ((P*Q) != nbProc) {
        if (me == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,"!!! CRITICAL ERROR : number of processors must be 4, 9, 16, ...\nAborting\n");
        }
        exit(1);
    }

    //createGridComm(me,P,Q);

    colMe = me / Q;
    ligMe = me % Q;

    MPI_Comm commCol, commLine; 
    //comes from http://static.msi.umn.edu/tutorial/scicomp/general/MPI/communicator.html
    /* Split comm into row and column comms */ 
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ligMe, colMe, &commLine); 
    /* color by row, rank by column */ 
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, colMe, ligMe, &commCol); 
    /* color by column, rank by row */ 

    printf("[%d]:My coordinates are i j (%d,%d)\n",me,ligMe,colMe); 

    // allocate memory for matrices
    double *A,*Btmp, *B,*C,*CC;
    A = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));
    B = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));
    Btmp = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));
    C = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));
    CC = (double *)malloc(blockSize*blockSize*sizeof(double));

    /* fill blocks with pseudo values

     NOTE : these values should not be changed so that
     the check below is valid
     */

    for(i=0;i<blockSize*blockSize;i++) {
        A[i] = 2.0+(double)me;
        B[i] = 1.0+(double)colMe;
        C[i] = (double)me / 10.0;
    }


    /* CAUTION : in the following, A,B C are supposed to be stored
     column after column, with each column of size blockSize.
     Thus A(0,0) and A(1,0) are contiguous in memory, but
     A(0,0) and A(0,1) are separated by blockSize cells.
     */

    // t = dclock(CLOCK_S);

    MPI_Status status;
    //main Loop
    for(i=0;i<Q;i++) {
        /*************************************
Etape 1 et 2: Transposition  column i (in step i) of B-blocks . stock in Btmp.  
         **************************************/

        if(colMe==i){

            if(ligMe==colMe) {
                MPI_Bcast(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,i,commCol);   
                // multadd(A,B,C,blockSize);
            }   
            else {
                int dest = ligMe * Q + i;//transpose !
                MPI_Send(B,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,dest,TAG_TRANSPOSE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Bcast(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,i,commCol);
                // mult(A,Btmp,CC,blockSize);
            }
        }
        else {

            int from = i*Q + colMe;// transpose !
            if(ligMe == i) {
                MPI_Recv(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,from,TAG_TRANSPOSE,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                // Broadcast on the column
                MPI_Bcast(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,i,commCol);
                // multadd(A,Btmp,C,blockSize);
            }
            else {
                MPI_Bcast(Btmp,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,i,commCol);
                // mult(A,Btmp,CC,blockSize);
            }

        }

        if(colMe == i)
            MPI_Reduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, C, blockSize*blockSize, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, colMe, commLine);
        else
            MPI_Reduce(CC,NULL,blockSize*blockSize,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,i,commLine);

    }
    //t = dclock(CLOCK_S) -t;

    printf("timing for %d : %f sec\n",me,t);

    // checking for result correctness
    int correct = 1;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(i=0;i<P;i++) {
        sum += 2.0+(ligMe*Q)+(double)i;
    }

    for(i=0;i<blockSize;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<blockSize;j++) {
            if (C[i+j*blockSize] <0.99999*((double)me/10.0 + sum*blockSize*(colMe+1.0)) || C[i+j*blockSize] >1.00001*((double)me/10.0 + sum*blockSize*(colMe+1.0)) ) {
                correct = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (correct != 1) {
        printf("multiplication result is not correct\n");
    }

    // free memory
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    free(CC);

    //releaseGridComm();

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Watch for the createGridComm(me,P,Q); I had to found something equivalent at http://static.msi.umn.edu/tutorial/scicomp/general/MPI/communicator.html

I also changed the test at the end of your code. Testing equality between double precision numbers will be too strict. Inequalities are better for floating-point numbers !

I hope this will help !
Bye,

Francis